# How to remove parent element from json in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

How to covert the below json

```
{"data":{"id":12,"name":"jeremy","email":"jeremy@test.com"}}
```

to

```
{"id":12,"name":"jeremy","email":"jeremy@test.com"}
```

I want to remove the "data" element from json.

Comment: Deserialize to `JObject`, select the value of the "data" property, convert it to a JSON string.

Comment: What @John said, `var result = JObject.Parse(input)["data"].ToString(Formatting.None);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With json.net it's fairly straightforward

```
var input = "{\"data\":{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"jeremy\",\"email\":\"jeremy@test.com\"}}";
var result = JObject.Parse(input)["data"].ToString(Formatting.None);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

<sub>***Note** : `Formatting.None` is only to preserve the formatting you had in your original example*</sub>

Or *Text.Json*

```
var result = JsonDocument.Parse(input).RootElement.GetProperty("data").ToString();
```

**Output**

```
{"id":12,"name":"jeremy","email":"jeremy@test.com"}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[JObject.Parse Method (String)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)

> Load a JObject from a string that contains JSON.

[JObject.Item Property (String)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm)

> Gets or sets the JToken with the specified property name.

[JToken.ToString Method (Formatting,JsonConverter[])](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm)

> Returns the JSON for this token using the given formatting and
> converters.

[Formatting Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm)

> None  0   No special formatting is applied.

---

**Text.Json**

[JsonDocument.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0)

> Provides a mechanism for examining the structural content of a JSON
> value without automatically instantiating data values.

[JsonDocument.RootElement Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.rootelement?view=net-5.0)

> Gets the root element of this JSON document

[JsonElement.GetProperty Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getproperty?view=net-5.0)

> Gets a JsonElement representing the value of a required property
> identified by propertyName.

Answer (score 0):

I have a follow up question on a scenario where I don't want to remove the root element.

```
{
  "keepMe": {
    "removeMe": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Foo",
        "email": "Foo@email.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Bar",
        "email": "Bar@email.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I wanted it to look like

```
{
  "keepMe": {
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Foo",
      "email": "Foo@email.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Bar",
      "email": "Bar@email.com"
    }
}
```

Using below would not work. Is there another way to do this?

```
var result = JObject.Parse(input)["keepMe"]["removeMe"].ToString(Formatting.None);

//{
//  "id": "1",
//  "name": "Foo",
//  "email": "Foo@email.com"
//},
//{
//  "id": "2",
//  "name": "Bar",
//  "email": "Bar@email.com"
//}

var result = JObject.Parse(input)["removeMe"].ToString(Formatting.None); //Null Reference
```

Found the answer using the `SelectToken` and `Replace` keyword

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(input);
jObj.SelectToken("keepMe").Replace(jObj.SelectToken("keepMe.removeMe"));
string result = jObj.ToString();
```